# Hide tab if content is empty using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

[Link to staging site](https://staging.myonlinemall.mk/)

[Link to product page](https://staging.myonlinemall.mk/product/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B0/%3E)
The first tab gets the description via shortcode,
The second one gets the short description via shortcode.
I want it so that if short description is empty, the tab gets deleted.

The tab is this one [image]

I used this code with jquery script but cant seem to get it to work

```
  // Remove tehnicki karakteristiki
function remove_tehnicki_karakteristiki() {
    if ( !is_singular(['product']) ){ // only on product page
    global $post, $product;
    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); // get short desc
    if (empty($short_description) ) {
        echo '<script>
        jQuery(#elementor-tab-title-1562).hide();
        </script>';
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Can you test using double quote for the Javascript selector like below?
jQuery("#elementor-tab-title-1562").hide();

Comment: @RupakNepali I tested it, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
function remove_tehnicki_karakteristiki() {
    if ( !is_singular(['product']) ){ // only on product page
        global $post, $product;
        $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); // get short desc

        echo "
        <script>
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $('.elementor-toggle .elementor-tab-content').filter(function () { 
                    let element = ($(this).find('.elementor-section-wrap').length == 0 ? $(this) : $(this).find('.elementor-section-wrap'))
                    if (!new RegExp('([A-z0-9])', 'gm').test(element.html())) element.closest('.elementor-toggle-item').hide();
                })
            });
    </script>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to get it done.

It doesn't search for media attached in <a href> tags

Comment: what do you mean search for media attached ?? This script hide any elementor-toggle-item with no content

Comment: Yes however it doesnt recognize when you upload photos to the text editor.
For example: 
<a href="https://myonlinemall.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/gif1.gif"><img src="https://myonlinemall.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/gif1.gif" alt="" width="360" height="360" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-14205" /></a>

Comment: Please provide a picture that shows exactly what you want, I still don't understand the relation between the photos you mentioned and the empty elements

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/1u74uty) here's the link to the photo

Comment: This still registers as no content and renders the tab invisibile

Comment: Check my answer update

Comment: Yes, works great!

Many thanks.